# jarvis-like ai python app

Tags: python, string, artificial-intelligence, string-matching

so we've all seen iron man, right? as a personal project i'm trying to create a jarvis-like ai. i dont need anything as sophisticated as jarvis by any means; that's just the best descriptor i can come up with.

i started by looking into conversational ai - chatbots - but that's not what i need. i feel like that method processes user input in a far different and more complex way than what i'm looking for. all i need is to give the ai a command and for the ai to match that command and run the appropriate code.

so then i stumbled upon libdiff. but that doesn't adequately serve my purposes. libdiff, as far as i've been able to use it, wont match strings where the wording is out of order. as far as i'm aware, at least, the order of wording in both strings has to be the same for libdiff to  make the match.

for example: 
user input: "what time is it?" 
won't match up with the command it *should* match up with: "what is the time?"

i'm not asking for spoonfed code, but can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: +1 Question of the year award :)

Comment: I am on the same pursuit jaja check out this. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_U_v9tRD68k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cool project, here are my first thoughts. I guess first you'd need voice to text, so you can effectively deal with the commands. Then you can apply more sophisticated methods on top of that. There is https://code.google.com/p/dragonfly/, but I've found it to be a bit too much for hacking a quick project out and I think supports primarily windows. However, maybe there is someone that offers a free rest service for this sort of thing, google is doing great work here http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/01/Voice-Driven-Web-Apps-Introduction-to-the-Web-Speech-API, but I don't think there is a python binding.

Then, the next task would be trying to find meaning in the text. So you'd need a parser (http://nltk.org/index.html) to look at question words like "what" and the subject "time", or some type of part of speech tagging. Of course doing this correctly in a general setting (of arbitrary inputs is much harder). It may be far easier to have some built in commands and then work to higher generality later.

If you want to do this in realtime it's even more challenging because you need to segment a realtime audio stream to determine when a sentence ends and when another begins.

Suppose, you want to solve a much simpler problem first though. Say just recognize a single command over microphone, like the word "open", and execute an action. You can do this quite easily if you are willing to train your voice. Motivated by this http://xa.yimg.com/kq/groups/24321415/1523383180/name/Speech_Recognition_seminar.pdf. You need pyaudio, numpy, scipy and if your want to see a code that implements this in python see https://gist.github.com/a-wild-tigger/5209781

Comment: lots of awesome information here, thanks. definitely kick started some ideas.

Comment: ambitious project. let me know if there are any other questions. I'd love to see what you come up with! good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to build an [Expert System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expert_system).

Have a look at this book [Prolog Programming for Artificial Intelligence - Ivan Bratko](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321417461). In Chapter 14 he talks about Expert systems.

Comment: thank you for putting a name to this and referencing the book, will definitely check it out.